# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to List<WebElement>

Tags: selenium

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class AutoSuggestiveDropdown {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");


        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

     driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/dropdownsPractise/");
        
        driver.findElement(By.id("autosuggest")).sendKeys("ind");

        Thread.sleep(3000L);

           List<WebElement> options =    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[class='ui-menu-item'] a")); //Error
       
       for(WebElement option : options) {
           
           
           if(option.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("India")) {

               option.click();

               break;

           }
           
           
       }
       
    
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the "error on line 7," can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used '`findElement`' in '`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[class='ui-menu-item'] a"))`'

You have to use '`findElements`' in '`driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li[class='ui-menu-item'] a"));`'